# Issues publishing and installing a npm package on a private registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I finished my package(1 js file) and I want to publish it on artifactory.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@company/package_name",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://artifactory_url"
  },
  "files": ["dist/index.js"],
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0"
  }
}
```

I publish it:

```
npm login --registry=https://artifacory_url --scope=@company
npm publish
```

my npm package is available now on artifactory (1 js file and package.json)

Now if I want to install it:

```
npm install @company/package_name --registry=https://artifacory_url
```

it complains that a dependency is not in the npm registry:

```
Not Found - GET https:artifactory_url/axios - not_found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'axios@^0.18.0' is not in the npm registry
```

which of course it's true, I don't have `axios` published in my registry, but I expected it to get it from the npm registry.

I'm not sure about the strategy to follow. 
I use `webpack`, so `axios` is already bundled in my `dist/index.js` file.  Should I treat it like a devDependencies like `tslint`? It seems that it is not a dev dependency to me...

Comment: I was wrong, I have configured my private registry to fallback to the public registry when the resolution of the package is not found.

Comment: @filipe how do you configure a fallback like this?

Comment: I updated my answer and it now includes how to do it using artifactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm devs are not going to facilitate/allow releasing to multiple registries at once because it could lead to issues like:

- A given version can be on one registry but not on the other
- The same version can be release on each registry with different code

To solve the problematic around private/public registries, most private registries use a proxy feature (if the package requested is in the private repo serve it, otherwise delegate the request to the public registry).

Many registry solution also offer a replication feature.

With those feature you should be able to publish only on one registry and serve it from multiple ones.

You are using artifactory, and they allow to configure it [rewriting](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-AutomaticallyRewritingExternalDependencies) external dependencies.

*Select the Enable Dependency Rewrite checkbox in the npm virtual
repository advanced configuration.*